# $\lambda (\tau)$ as a rational function of $j(\tau)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, modular-function

It is known that
$$j(\tau)=\frac{256(1-x)^3}{x^2}$$
where $x=\lambda (\tau)(1-\lambda (\tau))$ and $\lambda (\tau)$ is the modular lambda function.

But I came across the following statement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant):

> Rational functions of $j$ are modular, and in fact give *all modular functions*.

<s>So $\lambda (\tau)$ is a rational function of $j(\tau)$.</s> I tried to solve

$$j(\tau)=\frac{256(1-x)^3}{x^2}$$

for $x$ but ended up with long rooty expressions, not hinting at anything rational. That doesn't look good...

How can I express $\lambda (\tau)$ as a rational function of $j(\tau)$?

Comment: lambda is not invariant under the full modular group (so, in particular, cannot be a rational function of $j$ of course); lambda is a different kind of modular function than $j$ - this notion of modular function is quite ambiguous as it refers to various group invariances - $j$ is in a sense the fundamental one since it is invariant under the full group, while others like lambda are invaraiant only under specific subgroups